Why does VS Code show documentation for methods in some cases but shows 'any' in other cases
I'm new to VS Code and Node.js.
I followed a tutorial for creating an http server and noticed VS Code will show a useful documentation pop-up when hovering over a method.

I refactored the tutorial to test my understanding of passing functions and I noticed on the same method call VS Code shows 'any' in the pop-up instead of documentation.

Why is this?
Does this imply one technique of coding is preferred since it allows documentation?
I've tried googling this scenario but found nothing relevant.

This question is similar to: How to get intellisense for express.js in vscode. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

vscode uses typescript under the hood, which can check your javascript code. In the first example it is able to infer what the type will because you passed your callback directly createServer, but in the second it doesn't have that context.
Is one preferred over the other? I guess the answer depends on if you think types are important. If they are, you can add types to your second code snippet to have the same level of typing. Either by switching to Typescript or annotating it with jsdoc.
